# Why do I get a RuntimeException when I try to fill file lines into a vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am very new to the language and I try to get used to Clojure.

I want to read a file which contains Strings like:

```
prefix/FirstEntry
prefix/SecondEntry
prefix/ThirdEntry
```

I want to fill a vector with one line per field. I also need to get rid of the prefix. For this I read the file and replace the prefix/ with an empty String "".

```
(defn save-clean-lines [the-file] [the-prefix]
  (def vc-file (read-and-cut-file the-file the-prefix))
)

(defn read-and-cut-file
    [file, pref]
    (with-open[rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
                   (reduce conj [] (line-seq (rdr/replace pref ""))) ;;return a vector with deleted prefix
     )
```

When I test it I get the exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: *Unable to resolve symbol: read-and-cut-file in this context* on  `(def vc-file (read-and-cut-file the-file the-prefix))`

Why is that the case?

Comment: Please don't `def` outside of top level.  Also Clojure code is compiled in the order it is written.  Move your `read-and-cut-file` before your `save-and-cleant`

Answer (score 3):

```
(->> "data.txt"
     (slurp)
     (str/split-lines)
     (into [] (map (fn [s] (str/replace s #"^prefix/" "")))))
```

Comment: (into [] (map...) data)  is just mapv. Why bother with transducer?